# How could I make the UI auto update when there are new messages on the server with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a discord client for the apple watch with SwiftUI. I was able to make it get the messages from the server and display it, but it only displays them after the second time when you go to the view where the messages should be displayed. Does someone know how I could get the messages to auto update after every second and also make it so the messages get displayed directly after going to the view where the messages should be displayed. Thanks

Here's my code.

MessagesContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct MessagesContentView: View {

    var channel: ChannelObject

    var body: some View {

        List{

            ForEach(NetworkHandler.messages){msg in

                VStack(spacing: 5.0){

                    MessageView(URL: URL(string: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/\(msg.author.id)/\(msg.author.avatar).png?size=128")!, name: msg.author.username, message: msg.content, time: msg.time, edited: msg.edited)

                }

            }

        }
        .navigationBarTitle("#\(channel.name)")
        .onAppear(){

            NetworkHandler.getMsg(channelId: self.channel.id, limit: 100)

        }

    }

}
```

NetworkHandler.swift

```
static var messages: [MessageObject] = []

static func DoReq(type: String, method: String, url: String, data: String, header1:[String], header2: [String]){

   ...

case "channelMsg":

                    NetworkHandler.messages = []

                    do {

                        if let dataFromString = dataString.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {

                            let json = try JSON(data: dataFromString)

                            for (_, msg) in json {

                                guard let avatar: String = msg["author"]["avatar"].stringValue else { return }

                                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

                                let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
                                dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "hh:mm"

                                let dateFormatter2 = DateFormatter()
                                dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

                                let time = msg["timestamp"].stringValue

                                let index1 = time.index(time.startIndex, offsetBy: 0)
                                let index2 = time.index(time.startIndex, offsetBy: 10)
                                let time1 = time[index1 ..< index2]

                                let index3 = time.index(time.endIndex, offsetBy: -21)
                                let index4 = time.index(time.endIndex, offsetBy: -13)
                                let time2 = time[index3 ..< index4]

                                let timeConv = time1 + " " + time2

                                var timeConvString = String(timeConv)

                                //print(timeConv)

                                let timeFormat = dateFormatter.date(from: timeConvString)

                                var timeConverted = ""

                                if Calendar.current.isDateInYesterday(timeFormat!)
                                {
                                    timeConverted = "Yesterday, " + dateFormatter1.string(from: timeFormat!)
                                }
                                if Calendar.current.isDateInToday(timeFormat!) {
                                    timeConverted = "Today, " + dateFormatter1.string(from: timeFormat!)
                                }
                                if(Calendar.current.isDateInYesterday(timeFormat!) == false && Calendar.current.isDateInToday(timeFormat!) == false) {
                                    timeConverted = dateFormatter2.string(from: timeFormat!)
                                }

                                var edited = false

                                if(msg["edited_timestamp"].stringValue != ""){

                                    edited = true

                                }

                                let author = UserObject(id: msg["author"]["id"].stringValue, username: msg["author"]["username"].stringValue, avatar: avatar)

                                let message = MessageObject(id: msg["id"].stringValue, content: msg["content"].stringValue, channelId: msg["channel_id"].stringValue, author: author, time: timeConverted, edited: edited)

                                NetworkHandler.messages.append(message)

                            }
                        }

   ...

}

static func getUserMsg(channelId: String, limit: Int){

        let request_url = "https://discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/\(channelId)/messages?limit=\(limit)"

        NetworkHandler.DoReq(type:"usersMsg", method: "GET", url: request_url, data: "", header1:["\(NetworkHandler.token)", "Authorization"], header2:[])
    }
```

Comment: Are you familiar with Combine ? Can you please check the concept of `Publishers`, `Subscribers`, `Observable`, `ObservedObject`, `Environment` and `EnvironmentObject`.

Comment: @user1046037 no, but I'll take a look at it. Thanks

Comment: Refer: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/226/